# Insert children from a list to the the haskell rose tree leaves

Tags: algorithm, haskell, data-structures

I have the following rose tree in haskell:

```
data R = B [R]    -- B for Branch
```

I am trying to create the following function :

```
append :: R -> [R] -> R
```

This functions is supposed to take as input a rose tree (R) and a list of a rose trees [R] (assuming that number of leaves of R is equal to the number of elements from the list so each leaf gets a new branch) and add each element from [R] to the R and then return the final rose trees.

An example would be

```
append  B[B[B[],B[]],B[],B[]]  [ B[B[],B[]], B[], B[B[]], B[] ] = 
     B[B[B[B[B[],B[]]],B[B[]]],B[B[B[]]],B[B[]]]
```

The list in this case consist of 4 elements specifically :

```
B[B[],B[]]
B[]
B[B[]]
B[]
```

And each one got inserted accordingly

I managed to partially implement the solution:

```
append (B []) (l:list) = l
append (B [x]) list = append x list
```

However these steps just add the first element from the list to each leaf! So how could I implement this functionality so I can move around the list?

Comment: Can you write a function that will e.g. replace each `[]` in the leaves of its input tree with some constant value, like `[B[]]`? then you could try to somehow tweak _that_ function for your current task.

Comment: Is this related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69745847/adding-leaves-to-a-rose-tree?

Comment: "However these steps just add the first element from the list to each leaf!" I doubt very much that this is what that code is doing...

Comment: Well I think it would be hard to find a constant value which can never be used. I am thinking of a bread-first traversal of the rose and start adding from the list and when I hit the leaf level start inserting from the list , but I am not sure how to implement that

Comment: You might like [`mapAccumL`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:mapAccumL). Think about what its type says if you pick `a ~ [R]`.